# How do I save multiple combo box values to csv in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a combo box that will save multiple string values from filtering out specific words. This is captured when the user copies/pastes the string.
That all works fine. But I need to save the input to a csv file.
Currently, I've only been able to figure out how to save the first value in the combo box. If there are multiple values, its still only saving the first value in each combo box to a cell.
I am very new to C#, I kindly ask for a real simple response. Thank you so much.

```
        private void paste_error_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string aosinformation = Clipboard.GetText();
        string errorType = "";
        string errorIdent = "";
        int var4 = 0;
        int var5 = 0;
        int var6 = 0;
        int var7 = 0;
        string FoundError = "";
        string route1;
        string route2;



        while (aosinformation.IndexOf("ERROR (") > 0)
        {
            int var1 = aosinformation.IndexOf("ERROR (");
            int errorStart = aosinformation.Substring(var1, 400).IndexOf("TFR ");
            errorType = "TFR";
            if (aosinformation.Substring(var1, 400).IndexOf("notam") > errorStart)
            {
                errorStart = aosinformation.Substring(var1, 400).IndexOf("notam");
                errorType = "NOTAM";
             }
                  
             //Duplicate above IF statement as many times as needed to cover all error types

            if (errorStart > 0)
            {
                int var3 = aosinformation.IndexOf(".", var1);
                var4 = aosinformation.IndexOf(".", var3 + 1);
                var5 = aosinformation.IndexOf(")", var4 + 1);
                var6 = aosinformation.IndexOf("'", var5 + 1);
                var7 = aosinformation.IndexOf("'", var6 + 1);
                errorIdent = aosinformation.Substring(var6 +1 , var7 - var6 - 1).Trim(' ');
                aosinformation = aosinformation.Substring(var4 + 1, aosinformation.Length - var4 - 1);
                ErrorTypeCombo.Items.Add(errorType);
                ErrorIdentCombo.Items.Add(errorIdent);
            }
            else if (errorStart < 0)
            {
                errorStart = aosinformation.Substring(var1, 400).IndexOf("No continuous ");
                errorType = "Route Issue";
                int var3 = aosinformation.IndexOf(".", var1);
                var4 = aosinformation.IndexOf("'", var3 + 1);
                var5 = aosinformation.IndexOf("'", var4 + 1);
                var6 = aosinformation.IndexOf("'", var5 + 1);
                var7 = aosinformation.IndexOf("'", var6 + 1);
                route1 = aosinformation.Substring(var4 + 1, var5 - var4 -1);
                route2 = aosinformation.Substring(var6 + 1, var7 - var6 -1);

                errorIdent = route1 + " - " + route2;
                aosinformation = aosinformation.Substring(var4 + 1, aosinformation.Length - var4 - 1);
                ErrorTypeCombo.Items.Add(errorType);
                ErrorIdentCombo.Items.Add(errorIdent);

            }

            {

            }

            ErrorTypeCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ErrorIdentCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;



        }


    }
            {

                Excel.Workbook xlworkbook;
                Excel.Worksheet xlworksheet;
                object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                xlworkbook = xlap.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

                xlworksheet = 
               (Excel.Worksheet)xlworkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                Excel.Sheets worksheets = xlworkbook.Worksheets;
                Range rg = (Excel.Range)xlworksheet.Cells[1, 2];
                rg.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";



                xlworksheet.Cells[1, 1] = textBox1.Text;
                xlworksheet.Cells[1, 2] = dateTimePicker1.Value;
                xlworksheet.Cells[1, 3] = textBox2.Text.ToUpper();
                xlworksheet.Cells[1, 4] = textBox3.Text.ToUpper();
                xlworksheet.Cells[1, 5] = textBox4.Text.ToUpper();
                xlworksheet.Cells[1, 6] = comboBox1.Text;
                xlworksheet.Cells[1, 7] = ErrorTypeCombo.SelectedItem;
                xlworksheet.Cells[1, 8] = ErrorIdentCombo.Text
```

Comment: A combo box has a selected item and a list of possible values, what are you trying to save?

Comment: The winforms ComboBox has an [Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.items?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) property which you can enumerate with a for or a foreach loop.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. So the user could potentially write 4-5 different errors when they report a problem using the form. When they hit an "insert" button, it saves the data input to a csv. However, current code only saves the first input in the combo box, not the other 4 for example..

Comment: Maybe a good idea to show us your code what is saving the combo?

Comment: I've edited my question to make it clearer. Thanks Aldert.